# undefined reference to `curlpp::Cleanup::Cleanup()'

Tags: c++, curl

I'm a C++ newbie. I'm trying to compile the example code that comes with curlpp. I've used the command

```
g++ `/usr/local/bin/curlpp-config --cflags` `/usr/local/bin/curlpp-config --libs` example01.cpp
```

I get an error that references  the Cleanup function 
"/tmp/ccCfY4Ok.o:example01.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `curlpp::Cleanup::Cleanup()'"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to link curlpp library